# Use of # in JavaScript (outside of jQuery and CSS)?

Tags: javascript

I know of the use of # in jQuery AND CSS, but in a Vanilla JavaScript environment that has no jQuery or CSS intervention, does # have ANY use?

Comment: This kind of seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377) where the X is related to filtering JavaScript code.

Comment: @xufox No, I'm simply asking if the # character has any known usage as an operator in JavaScript other than the jQuery or CSS related...

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript. `#` doesn't have any special meaning in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in JavaScript you can use the character `#` inside strings.

For example, `#` begins an [ID selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#id-selectors) in CSS, which you can use in JS:

```js
document.querySelector('#someID');
```

And in URLs, a `#` begins the hash. In JavaScript you can get the hash of an object which implements [`URLUtils`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils) functionality using the [`hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/hash) property:

```js
location.hash; // '#someHash'
location.hash = '#anotherHash';
```

You can also use it as a delimiter for your strings:

```js
var arr = ['ab', 'c', 'de', 'fg', 'h', 'ij']; // This is longer
var arr = 'ab#c#de#fg#h#ij'.split('#');       // This is shorter
```

And of course you may want a string to contain the `#` character. In this case, use `#`:

```js
var str = 'This string has a number sign at the end: #';
```

Apart from strings, you can also use `#` in regular expressions:

```js
var rg = /#/; // This matches the character `#` literally
```

Comment: Quite valid answer, even though all of those are just "JS strings can contain any character" :)

Comment: @Amadan true, but it's useful in that it makes clear that assuming JavaScript code won't contain a "#" character is unwise. (It's not clear what the OP is really about of course.)

Answer (score 0):

No. Neither does <strike>the backtick (well, so far), nor</strike> the english pound symbol, the at-sign, or that weird poo smiley. There are many more characters that are not used in the grammar than there are those that are.

(And `#id` is not a thing of either jQuery or JavaScript, but of XML and DOM API.)

Comment: @Xufox: Oh... didn't notice it is already usable outside of transpilers. Will correct now... Also, thanks.